# How to get to another function if a radio button is checked? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

When a radio is checked, I want to get to another function by clicking on a button and if none of them are checked, I want to tell the user "you need to choose one of the options".

Here's a part of my code:

```
function activeSection2(){
//montre la section2 - #Perso
document.getElementById("Accueil").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("Perso").style.display="block";


document.forms[1].elements[0].addEventListener("click",activeSection3,false)
```

The last line of the code is what I want to activate when one of the radios are checked.

Here are my radios :

```
<form>
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Humains</legend>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadGUE" name="rGroupe1"><p id="GUE">Guerrier</p>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadVOL" name="rGroupe1"><p id="VOL">Voleur</p>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadCLE" name="rGroupe1"><p id="CLE">Clerc</p>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadMAG" name="rGroupe1"><p id="MAG">Magicien</p>
                    </fieldset>

                   <fieldset>
                   <legend>Demi-humains</legend>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadNAI" name="rGroupe1"><p id ="NAI">Nain</p>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadELF" name="rGroupe1"><p id ="ELF">Elf</p>
                       <input type="radio" id="aRadHAL" name="rGroupe1"><p id="HAL">Halfelin</p>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: can you give use some code please

Comment: @DanyCode here you go

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fnA() {
  alert("fn A is doing stuff...");
}

function fnB() {
  alert("fn B is doing stuff...");
}


document.getElementById("testBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  // Get the currently selected radio value
  var checked = document.querySelector("[name='fn']:checked");
  
  if(!checked) {
    // No radios checked
    alert("Please select one option...");
  } else {
    // Use the checked radio value as a function name - and trigger it!
    window[checked.value]();
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="fn" value="fnA"> Use fn A<br>
<input type="radio" name="fn" value="fnB"> Use fb B<br>

<input type="button" value="TEST" id="testBtn">
```